# having to manually add 'https://' to a url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, https, dnsimple

I have just added ssl to a VPS I'm running (first time so sorry if this is a newb thing to ask).

The SSL is working fine but I noticed when navigating to the URL from anywhere but my development machine, I have to manually add the https:// to the start of the url.

would anybody happen to know what may be causing this?

I'm using nginx on ubuntu 14.04 and dnsimple for my DNS records.

Any help would be much appreciated and if you need any more info let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I think you are supposed to redirect users coming from port 80 (HTTP) to port 443 (HTTPS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a redirect http to https.

An example:

```
server {
    listen         80;
    server_name    my.domain.com;
    rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify for anybody who comes across this question (and myself in the future no doubt). The server block specified in the answer has to be declared as a separate server statement else you'll get a redirect loop error.